# Convert between double and byte array, for transfer over ZigBee API?

Tags: c++, zigbee

I'm trying to take two doubles (GPS coordinates) and send them over the ZigBee API to another ZigBee receiver unit, but I don't know how to decompose the doubles into byte arrays and then re-compose them back into their original form once they are transferred.

Basically, I need to turn each double into an array of eight raw bytes, then take that raw data and reconstruct the double again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're doing is called [type punning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning).

Use a union:

```
union {
  double d[2];
  char b[sizeof(double) * 2];
};
```

Or use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
char* b = reinterpret_cast<char*>(d);
```

Comment: I did some more reading on unions and got it to work that way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a rather unsafe way to do it:

```
double d = 0.123;
char *byteArray = (char*)&d;

// we now have our 8 bytes

double final = *((double*)byteArray);
std::cout << final; // or whatever
```

Or you could use a reinterpret_cast:

```
double d = 0.123;
char* byteArray = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d);

// we now have our 8 bytes

double final = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(byteArray);
std::cout << final; // or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically a double is already eight bytes. Please verify this on your operating system by comparing sizeof(double) and sizeof(char). C++ doesn't declare a **byte** , usually it means **char**

If it is indeed true.

```
   double x[2] = { 1.0 , 2.0};

   double* pToDouble = &x[0];
   char* bytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pToDouble);
```

Now bytes is what you need to send to ZigBee